# Unwanted self shadowing

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit, shadow, directional-light

I have an ARKit App using SceneKit to render.
I am using a directional light that casts shadows onto an invisible floor plane. In order to do this I have to (?) use `shadowMode = .deferred` on the light. But this results in the ugly self shadowing in the image:

[image: Box casting self shadow]
How can I avoid this and still keep the shadow on the floor plane? The lighting seems fine with `shadowMode = .forward`, but then I get no shadow on the floor.

Answer (score 0):

There are few methods that could fix this problem.

1. To use .constant [SCNMaterial.LightingModel](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterial/lightingmodel).
2. To manipulate with [SCNMaterialProperty](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterialproperty)
3. To manipulate with [categoryBitMask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1407994-categorybitmask) of the node and the light source.
   Hope it helps!